# about: Graphics Cards and HDMI supporting

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi

I'm planing to buy a new Graphic Card, with PHYSX and HDMI.

Nvidia have a lot of pretty Graphic Cards, with a little expensive price.

The only cards which contain (**Physx & HDMI**) in same time; are: 9800GX2 and GTX295, and they are very expensive for my budget.

The question is: ***Can I get a pure quality of DVI > HDMI adapter, like using a HDMI direct output? with 1080p e.g. from DVI output?***

I'm weird about that, because one of my lovley things is using PC and play games with HD Content.

Finally, are this graphic card (GTX280) is good for gaming like Crisys and FarCry 2? without high temp. or low number of frames ... e.g. ?

sorry for my fragile language.

Thank you for all.

Answer (score 3):

DVI can absolutely support HD either natively or over an HDMI adapter. 1080p is 1920x1080 which is handled no problem. All of the cards you have listed are above the requirements for Crisis, but performance depends on more than the card.